# What is Pre-rendering and how does it differ to Server-side rendering?

Tags: javascript, performance, server-side-rendering

I've recently been using a tool that pre-renders my views, it's great because without any effort on my part it has made a considerable decrease to the load time of my website.

However I'm unsure of how pre-rendering differs from server-side rendering, what the benefits are, and when you would chose pre-rendering over SSR?

Comment: Look at it here https://www.toptal.com/front-end/client-side-vs-server-side-pre-rendering

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correct, pre-rendering is a special case of SSR which results in a set of ***static*** HTML files (without JS at all). However SSR may also be used *partially* to produce initial rendering.